# Knockout observableArray push not working

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following markup:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td style="padding-left: 150px;">
        <ul id="items" data-bind='foreach: Items'>
           <li>
              <span class="title" data-bind="text: $data.Title"></span>
            <li>  
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the following javascript:

```
$(function () { 
  var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.Items= ko.observableArray();

        self.arrayChanged = function (array) {
            $.each(array, function (i, obj) {
                self.Items.push(obj);
            });
        };
    };
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#items")[0]);
    viewModel.arrayChanged($.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items))'));               
});
```

The above is a much simplified version of what I'm trying to do. In the above

```
self.Items.push(obj);
```

doesn't work as it fails to push new items on the Items observableArray. I also tried using

```
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.Experiences, obj);
```

to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the JSON for `Model.Items` look like?

Comment: To be more specific - are you sure that this `$.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items))')` is array?

Comment: in case of great emergency use self.Items.valueHasMutated()

Comment: Yes, Ilya, $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items))') produces an array.

Comment: John, I had tried using self.Items.valueHasMutated() before and it didn't help.

Comment: Here, I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7kkbyhL/) for you. Can you try to reproduce your issue with it (passing your json maybe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
self.arrayChanged = function (array) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(array)    
    self.Items(arr)
};
```

convert json to object then pass array of objects to `Items`

Comment: Yes, pushing each object into the array is not great because it triggers as many dependency resolutions as you have items in your input.  This answer assigns all your input to the array at once.

Comment: Raheel, I already pass in the array using $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items))'). I tried using your suggestion by passing in Json string with '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Items))' instead and then using self.Items(arr) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, never mind, this suggestion did work after a little bit of playing around. So, thanks a lot.